# Enabling SSL with Spring Boot restful apis for production

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I want to add SSL certificate to restful web API, I had tried to by adding self signed certificate but it can not be used for production.

How to add aws public certificate to it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you tell us what you tried and why that did not work as expected? This will help us giving more focused answers. Please [edit] your question to include further information.

Answer (score 2):

Try with self signed key first.

Generate a SSL key by this Command.

```
keytool -genkey -alias https-example -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365 -keystore https-example.jks
```

A file named `https-example.jks` will get generated by above command so put that inside `src/main/resources` along with `application.properties`

put below code in **application.properties**

```
server.port=8443

server.ssl.key-alias=https-example
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:https-example.jks
```

access api url like below.

```
https://localhost:8443/apiURL
```

For AWS by SSL certificates from one of the many vendors like GoDaddy etc. and put those certificates and update application.properties.

Comment: i had done that but it is self signed certificate i want to know how to do this with public certificate generated by aws for this i had used. command                              
keytool -importcert -file myCertificate.crt -alias tomcat -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Comment: purshase SSL from godaddy or any other vendor and they will generate some certificates so just put them inside resources and update the application.properties file accordingly.